# Detecting SSH agent forwarding

Tags: ssh

How can I find out whether an SSH connection has been established with or without agent forwarding?

I'm trying to do the following:

```
ssh-add -D (delete all stored keys)
ssh --vvv something
ssh-add (adding key)
ssh --vvv something
```

and compare output, but I can see only subtle differences.

Comment: For reference, check out this nice article: http://blog.joncairns.com/2013/12/understanding-ssh-agent-and-ssh-add. It points you to a nice GitHub repo with a `ssh-find-agent` script for finding and using existing ssh-agents, very handy! The repo has some examples in the README. You might be able to detect if ssh-agent is enabled like that, along with inspecting the SSH config files, rather than looking at the SSH output.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When ssh agent forward is enabled on the client (`ForwardAgent yes` on `~/.ssh/config`) and is also enabled on the remote server `AllowAgentForwarding yes`, when logging to the remote server the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` should exist. Then if you log into another server (you public key must reside on this third server) you should not be prompted for any password.

To clarify:

```
home$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase ...
Identity added ...
$ ssh  hostA
hostA$ env | grep SSH_AUTH_SOCK
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/...
$ ssh hostB
hostB$
```

Comment: The `ssh-add` is what did the trick for me.  I'd been working for months not knowing about that.  Then I switched desktops from Unity to LXDE and agent key forwarding stopped working.

Comment: @MarkHudson For some reason when running LXDE you have to run `ssh-add` every time you open a new console window. So I added that command line to the end of `~/.bash_profile`, and now the authentication agent forwarding works every time transparently!

Comment: @PaulBernal You shouldn't really need to do that, I imagine you don't have `ssh-agent` set up correctly. See http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh

Comment: m2c: the file in `"${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}"` is a socket, you can test it with `if [[ ! -S "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" ]]; then echo "warn: no forward agent detected ('${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}' is not a socket)"; fi`

Answer (score 7):

Checking environment for `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is good for direct ssh connections.

If you use proxies (`proxy_command`) you might have a connction that looks like:

`local` -> `hostA` -> `hostB` -> `hostC` -> `hostD`

If agent forwarding is active on all those hosts, then `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` will be set and "contains" your ssh key from `local` on all hosts.

Now suppose agent forwarding is disabled on `hostB` but enabled on `hostC`. `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` will be set on `hostD` but it will actually be "empty". Of course the agent is forwarded but only from `hostC` to `hostD`. The chain is broken.

Now to check if actually the key is available on `hostD` you can simply call `ssh-add`. It will exit with code 1 in any case, but if the key is unavailable it will show this on `stderr`:

> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

So you can check for the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` plus make sure `ssh_add` has no output.