# How can script execute itself via some exec again?

Tags: shell, shell-script

I'm making script for backing up data from server, it's gonna use ssh and scp many times. My private key is password-protected, but I'm using environment without any ssh agent.

I'd like to put condition to script, that check whether script is launched using [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18940/13428). If there is no ssh agent running, I would like to use `exec ssh-agent <original script relaunch>`.

How to do that?

Comment: it looks like you answered your own question :)

Comment: Well... no, I don't know how to execute script again with exact cmdline arguments, that was used for first time :)

Comment: What happens when ssh-agent always fails in 1 second? Endless loop? Why not put thecode of your current script inside a function and call that function again-and again-and-again and stop after some failures?

Answer (score 4):

To wrap the script itself use `$0` (program/script name) and `$@` (the expanded list of arguments: same as `"$1" "$2"...`).

```
if something; then
    exec ssh-agent "$0" "$@"
fi
```